# PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character even though no metacharacters are dangling

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check if a string matches the pattern of a complex number with the format `x+yi` or `x-yi`.
My regex for this purpose is `^\d+(\.\d+)?[-\+]\d+(\.\d+)?i` and it works just fine on regexr (regexr.com/572bb).

Here is my minimal example in java:

```
public class ExampleClass {
    public static void main(){
        String comp = "3+5i";
        System.out.println(comp.matches("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?[-\\+]\\d+(\\.\\d+)?i"));
    }
```

It throws the above exception. Here it is in full:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
```

The "+" it's complaining about is this one: `[-\\+]` but it doesn't seem like it's dangling since I escaped it. I am a beginner, so I would appreciate any help I can get. Thank you!

Comment: @WJS Fixed that :) That wasn't the issue though

Comment: It's working for me. Please see code [**here**](https://onlinegdb.com/Bk_Qt0qp8).

Comment: @Mandy8055 I'm trying to understand this part: `[-+\\\\]`
Doesn't this just say "allow as many '-' as you want" and then it escapes two semicolons? I'm very confused.

Comment: @Mandy8055 I'm sorry for probably being annoying but the way I learned about regex, I thought square brackets means "match any character in the set" and in order to allow the "+" character, I have to escape it because it's a metacharacter. Does regex work differently in Java or am I just being kind of dumb?

EDIT: didn't see your edit :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216310/discussion-between-flo-klar-and-mandy8055).

Comment: You don't need to escape.  `"^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?[-+]\\d+(\\.\\d+)?i"` will work.

Comment: Other than missing an end semi-colon, it worked fine for me.

Comment: You don't want an optional minus sign before the real part of the number?

Answer (score -1):

To represent complexes x + yi, x-yi, you could do it like this

```
String comp = "3+5i";
System.out.println(comp.matches("^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?[+,-][0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?[i]$"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
Unfortunately, your solution doesn't allow me to input doubles or multi-digit numbers like "283.482+28.382i".

Comment: It also matches `"3,5i"`.

Comment: @Flo Klar, You are right, I did not think about the floating numbers, the expression would be `^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?[+,-][0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?[i]$`

Answer (score -1):

The issue was nothing to do with that expression at all. I used
`String.split("+");` elsewhere in my code and neglected to escape that "+".

For posterity: Escape metacharacters when using `String.split();`.